# Why won't my new activity start on startActivity(intent)?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-recyclerview

So I have created a method ("OnNoteClick") to help get the Adapter Postition of a Recycler View and send its details to a different activity. I used this video to make the method[RecyclerView-OnClick video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=69C1ljfDvl0)

However, for some reason it won't open the activity on the click of the reyclerview position.

Below I have listed the activity code, and the RecylerView Adapter code.

ConstituencyKerry.java

```
package com.example.fypfinaltrial;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ConstituencyKerry extends AppCompatActivity implements ClareMembersRecyclerView.OnNoteListener {

    private ArrayList<String> mNames = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> mParties = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> mImageUrls = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_constituency_kerry);

        getImages();
    }

    private void getImages(){


        mImageUrls.add("https://data.oireachtas.ie/ie/oireachtas/member/id/Michael-Healy-Rae.D.2011-03-09/image/large");
        mNames.add("Michael Healy-Rae");
        mParties.add("Independent");

        mImageUrls.add("https://data.oireachtas.ie/ie/oireachtas/member/id/Pa-Daly.D.2020-02-08/image/large");
        mNames.add("Pa Daly");
        mParties.add("Sinn Féin");


        mImageUrls.add("https://data.oireachtas.ie/ie/oireachtas/member/id/Brendan-Griffin.D.2011-03-09/image/large");
        mNames.add("Brendan Griffin");
        mParties.add("Fine Gael");


        mImageUrls.add("https://data.oireachtas.ie/ie/oireachtas/member/id/Danny-Healy-Rae.D.2016-10-03/image/large");
        mNames.add("Danny Healy-Rae");
        mParties.add("Independent");

        mImageUrls.add("https://data.oireachtas.ie/ie/oireachtas/member/id/Norma-Foley.D.2020-02-08/image/large");
        mNames.add("Norma Foley");
        mParties.add("Fianna Fáil");

        initClareRV();
    }

    private void initClareRV(){

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv_Kerry_Members);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        RecyclerView adapter = new RecyclerView(this, mNames, mParties, mImageUrls, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNoteClick(int position) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ConstituencyKerry.this, MembersMapDetailed.class);
        intent.putExtra("EXTRA_KEY_NAME", mNames.get(position));
        intent.putExtra("EXTRA_KEY_PARTY", mParties.get(position));
        intent.putExtra("EXTRA_KEY_IMAGE", mImageUrls.get(position));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

RecyclerView.java

```
ublic class RecyclerView extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{


    private  static final  String TAG = "ClareMembersRV";

    //vars
    private ArrayList<String> mNames = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> mParties = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> mImageUrls = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context mContext;
    private OnNoteListener mOnNoteListener;

    public ClareMembersRecyclerView(Context context, ArrayList<String> names, ArrayList<String> parties, ArrayList<String> imageUrls, OnNoteListener onNoteListener){

        mNames = names;
        mParties = parties;
        mImageUrls = imageUrls;
        mContext = context;
        this.mOnNoteListener = onNoteListener;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateViewHolder: called.");

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_members_clare, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view, mOnNoteListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: called.");

    Glide.with(mContext)
            .asBitmap()
            .load(mImageUrls.get(position))
            .into(holder.image);

    holder.name.setText(mNames.get(position));

    holder.party.setText(mParties.get(position));

    holder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: clicked on an image" + mNames.get(position));
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Profile: " + mNames.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MembersMapDetailed.class);
           // intent.putExtra(mNames.get(position),mParties,mImageUrls);
                    }
    });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mImageUrls.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        CircleImageView image;
        TextView name;
        TextView party;
        OnNoteListener onNoteListener;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView, OnNoteListener onNoteListener) {
            super(itemView);
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgClareCircle);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvClareName);
            party = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvClareParty);
            this.onNoteListener = onNoteListener;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onNoteListener.onNoteClick(getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }
        public interface OnNoteListener{
            void onNoteClick(int position);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the logcat? Did you register the new activity in the manifest?

Comment: You forgot to set the `ViewHolder` itself as the `OnClickListener` for its `View`; e.g., in your `ViewHolder`'s constructor, `itemView.setOnClickListener(this);`. You probably then want to remove the `holder.image.setOnClickListener(...)` call you currently have in `onBindViewHolder()`, which I assume you added for testing purposes.